# Add a character on top of a span

Tags: html, css

I have a span next to my h4 look like this.

[image]

I want to stack a white right angle bracket on top of my span.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<h4 class="pp">
  <span class="cr"></span>
  Laptop
</h4>
```

**CSS**

```
.cr {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ff7c00;
    border-radius: .25em;
    width: 1.3em;
    height: 1.3em;
    float: left;
    margin-right: .5em;
}
```

---

I tried

```
 <h4 class="pp">
    <span class="cr"></span>
    <span>></span>
    Laptop
 </h4>
```

I got

[image]

How would one go about do this?

Comment: JSFiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/b1dLmy5p/1/

Comment: `<span class="cr">></span>` and set the color in the css (and tweak position as needed)

Comment: Isn't putting something "on top" of a block element the same as putting it inside? Do you need different z-values or something odd like that?

Comment: @rlemon I tried that I got this : https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxe3mz73yo1ztmz/%202018-02-15%20at%202.40.35%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b1dLmy5p/7/

Comment: @ihue I didn't mean in a new span, I meant in the one you have. see Julians fiddle.

Comment: You want the arrow to be inside of the box, so put it inside of the box by putting it in the `.cr` span

Comment: Ohh ok. Got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for? Its technically inside the box rather than on top, but I think that's what you wanted to achieve, no?

```css
.cr {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ff7c00;
    border-radius: .25em;
    width: 1.3em;
    height: 1.3em;
    float: left;
    margin-right: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
 <h4 class="pp">
      <span class="cr"> > </span>
      Laptop
  </h4>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to achieve, thank-you guys so much for your help. It works.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear!

Comment: @ihue try to avoid `<` or `>` as a text in HTML, the browser might mix them with tags...[**See this**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)...use entity-names or pseudo classes for it...

Answer (score 4):

[***Dont use `<` or `>` signs in your text, the browser might mix them with tags...***](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

***Solution1***: Using HTML Entities

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.cr {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff7c00;
  border-radius: .25em;
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="pp">
  <span class="cr">&gt;</span> Laptop
</h4>
```

***Solution2***: Use `:before` pseudo css to the `.cr` class

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.cr {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ff7c00;
  border-radius: .25em;
  width: 1.3em;
  height: 1.3em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.cr:before {
  content: ">";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<h4 class="pp">
  <span class="cr"></span> Laptop
</h4>
```

Comment: Why do this when you can just insert the character into the actual span?

Comment: @Huangism I will avoid to use `>` as the `text` because [**See this**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Comment: You can still insert the character into the original span with the entity, there is no need for the pseudo class complication